# What is the purpose of the .r-version

Tags: r, renv

I am working with an RStudio project and using `renv` for package control.  In my `renv.lock` file, the version of R I am using is `4.0.2`, and that indeed is the version of R being used by the project. However, I have a file in the root of project, `.r-version` whose content is

```
3.4.4
```

What is the purpose of this file, how do I update it, or should I just delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of what the purpose of the `r-version` file, but if you are using `renv` you can delete it.